# Setting Uploaded Image as Background using Javascript in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application, I have so far managed to upload images to the server. Now I would like to set an uploaded image as a background dynamically using javascript in ASP.NET MVC5. Here is my code. This part reads file from local storage

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () 
{
    jQuery("#imageBrowes").change(function () 
    {
        var File = this.files;
        if (File && File[0]) 
        {
            ReadImage(File[0]);
        }

    })

})


var ReadImage = function(file) 
{
     var reader = new FileReader;
     var image = new Image;

     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     reader.onload = function(_file) 
     {
         image.src = _file.target.result;
         image.onload = function() 
         {
             var height = this.height;
             var width = this.width;
             var type = file.type;
             var size = ~~(file.size / 1024) + "KB";

             jQuery("#targetImg").attr('src', _file.target.result);
             jQuery("#description").text("Size:" + size + ", " + height + "X " + width + ", " + type + "");
             jQuery("#imgPreview").show();

         }

     }

}
```

This part stores the image into the file server system:

```
var ClearPreview = function(){

jQuery("#imageBrowes").val('');
jQuery("#description").text('');
jQuery("#imgPreview").hide();

}

var Uploadimage = function()
{

var file = jQuery("#imageBrowes").get(0).files;
var data = new FormData;
data.append("ImageFile", file[0]);

jQuery.ajax({

type: "Post",
url: "/Home/ImageUpload",
data: data,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function (response) {
ClearPreview();
jQuery("#uploadedImage").append('<img src="/elements-images/' + response + '" class="img-responsive thumbnail"/>');

}

})

}
```

This the action that is called up in the above javascript:

```
public ActionResult ImageUpload(ProductViewModel model)
{
    var file = model.ImageFile;

    if (file != null)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var extention = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        var filenamewithoutextension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);

        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/elements-images/" + file.FileName));


    }

    return Json(file.FileName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

So basically the image file is saved into elements-images folder. How do I then set a specific image from that folder into a background image?

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript side preview**

For javascript side preview of the file, Please change your this line

```
jQuery("#targetImg").attr('src', _file.target.result);
```

to

```
jQuery("#targetImg").attr('src', "data:" + file.type + ";base64," +  btoa(_file.target.result) );
```

**Preview after upload on server**

To show image after server response your code seems to be correct. It seems you need to change this line in action result

```
return Json(file.FileName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

so it looks like this

```
public ActionResult ImageUpload(ProductViewModel model)
{
    var file = model.ImageFile;
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    if (file != null)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var extention = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        var filenamewithoutextension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);

        file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/elements-images/" + file.FileName));


    }

    return Json(fileName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Comment: I have changed it, but what does this do?

Comment: your _file.target.result is binary data, you can't directly set it in src. My code is changing it to base64 string and you can embed the base64 string in image src. Doesn't it show image now in targetImg?

Comment: I got a build error when I changed the line in my action. I do get a preview after up load, but what I am looking for is how to set the saved image as a background image using using the .attr() and .css() methods. That is what I am not sure of.